# Bulging filaments - How can catch them before they go in the printer

Tags: filament

After multiple jams from bulging filaments on two spools I'm getting frustrated.  One, right before a job was done.

Is there something I can do to prevent these bulges in filaments from ruining jobs?

What can I do to prevent this from happening in the future before it's a disaster?

He's a picture of one I found using google.

[image]

Comment: What are you looking for in an answer? Do you reckon there is a better way than painstakinly physically inspecting the filament or just buying better quality filament to begin with?

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand. I have two questions in the post.  I can put them in here I guess.   Is there something I can do to prevent these bulges in filaments from ruining jobs?

What can I do to prevent this from happening in the future before it's a disaster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's my picture :-)

I use a filament monitor with an encoder wheel that pauses the print if the filament stops moving (because a bulge got stuck, or filament ran out, or the hot end jammed, or whatever). I have a bunch of these on multiple printers: http://www.toybuilderlabs.com/products/tunell-3d-printer-filament-monitor

The Tunell monitor works with Sailfish, Marlin, and Smoothie to my knowledge. This particular one doesn't work with Repetier, but you can wire up a simple encoder wheel to use Repetier's filament monitor functionality.

Like other people have mentioned, you should avoid cheap filament, and return spools with bulges. I personally only see bulges like that maybe every 20 spools or less.

Comment: I couldn't get a good picture so pulled one off google.   :-) hope your ok with that.

Comment: No worries! Link to the original post if anyone wants it: https://plus.google.com/114722716901025057698/posts/aioDrYXYe3J

Comment: That's why "The Google" has it.  :-)  I understand now.

Answer (score 6):

How to catch *and* fix these on the fly? That would be difficult..

But this is an issue you really should not have.

[Could it be an issue with filament storage?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/84/47)

Or is it coming from the manufacturer with these bulges? If so, I would try contacting ( you may have gotten a bad batch? ), or finding a new retailer if this happens often.

I have gone through a lot of pounds of both ABS and PLA and never come across this.

Comment: I agree. I have never seen this myself.

Comment: I can't determine where the incident occurs.  In the supply chain?  With my friends kid running around like a banshee?  Who knows.  I've just had it happen to me twice.  A bit frustrating.

Comment: Short of doing a bare eye inspection, or rolling out and rewrapping every single roll, I don't see how these could easily be detected when you first get them. My best suggestion would to get a plasticware tote and keep all of your filament in there. This will prevent them for getting moisture damage, and potential damage from being moved around often; if you keep seeing these, make note of on which filament, if they all came from the same place, or were all port of the same order, I would be contacting them for a refund / replacement.

Answer (score 4):

**Bottom line: *The easiest way to prevent this is to avoid cheap filament.***

You can get mid-grade filament for a few dollars more than the ultra cheap stuff.

In other words I tried out some 10$ stuff from ebay, and while it might print for a little while it notoriously clogged in any prints greater than 1hr.

20-25$ is the going rate for mid-grade filament on amazon and check the reviews I've had good consistency there.

Comment: There's a distinct possibility that something physical happened after I purchased it and it got into my hands.  I don't have 24/7 surveillance on them.  I know it's not my labrador because it didn't have teeth marks anywhere.  Other than that, it's a mystery.   :-)

Comment: @Citizen could have been the humidity in the air too.  I don't remember what all filaments are sensitive to that, but some are.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 maybe the Labrador was standing there breathing on it. My dog stands and sniffs this stuff for as long as we let her ...

Answer (score 4):

There is a filament width sensor design at http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:454584 -- cleverly, the author tweaked Marlin so it adjusts extrusion in real time to correct for variations.

That said, I agree with several others that buying filament with better quality control, and keeping it dry and unchewed by Labradors, should be enough. :)